# iOS Safari transition absolute position

Tags: html, css

I came across a weird issue on iOS Safari.
The following Fiddle works with all browsers except mobile safari.
The transition is not working correctly.

Expected behaviour:
The text is moved to the top left corner, quite smoothly.

Actual behaviour (only iOS safari):
The text jumps to the top left corner and transforms a little bit with the transition applied.

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="ref" class="logo">
    some text
  </div>
</div>
```

//CSS

```
.container{
 background: blue;
 width: 500px;
 height: 500px;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 position: relative;
}

.logo{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background: orange;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transition: all 3s;
}

.logo-move{
  top: 1.25rem;
  left: 1.25rem;
  transform: none;
}
```

//Javascript

```
setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById("ref").className = 'logo logo-move'
},2500)
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/pv2k4nuw/19/

How to make it work on iOS Safari?

Comment: Thing is, Safari fell behind in terms of compliance a good while ago, so if something doesn't work on it while it works in say, Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox, statistically that'd be a bug in Safari. That said, *what is your question*? How to make it work in Safari?

Comment: Yes, how to make it work in safari.